# MarkLogic unable to assign variable to cts:document-query()

Tags: marklogic

How can I assign a variable to cts:document-query().  I have sample code to read from file system then assign variable to document-query(). But it spool out errors.

case 1) working without assign variable to document-query.

```
let $list-pdf := cts:search(/,cts:and-query((
                          cts:directory-query("/pdf/"),
                          cts:document-query(("/pdf/US1610547.pdf", "/pdf/US1696102.pdf", 
                         "/pdf/US1953345.pdf"))) 
 for $pdf in $list-pdf 
return base-uri($pdf)
```

return result:

```
 /pdf/US1610547.pdf
 /pdf/US1696102.pdf
```

Case 2 - I assign variable to document-query() after reading from file system. MarkLogic gives me errors.

```
let $pdf := xdmp:filesystem-file("/output/listpdf.txt")
let $pdfs := tokenize($pdf,"\n")
let $list-pdf := cts:search(/,cts:and-query((
                          cts:directory-query("/pdf/"),
                          cts:document-query(($pdfs))
                                                                    ))) 
for $pdf in $list-pdf 
return base-uri($pdf)
```

return errorcode:

```
[1.0-ml] XDMP-URI: cts:document-query(("/pdf/US1610547.pdf", "/pdf/US1696102.pdf",...)) -- Invalid URI format: ""
```

Comment: A general comment: it would be more straightforward to just use `cts:uris("/pdf/", (), cts:document-query($pdfs))` instead of retrieving the docs with a `cts:search()`, iterating through, and getting each document `base-uri()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message indicates that the result of tokenization includes an empty string item among the sequence of URIs:

```
-- Invalid URI format: ""
```

You can apply a predicate after tokenizing to exclude empty strings (or use more elaborate logic, depending on how much your input can be trusted), i.e.:

```
let $pdfs := tokenize($pdf,"\n")[. ne ""]
```